# Angular Js- Why If condition is not running?

Tags: angularjs, loops, if-statement, comparison

Hi I am trying to run this chunk of code where I am comparing two values but seems like the comparison is not working .

```
for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.subcats.length - 1; i++)
            {
                console.log($scope.subcategory_id);
                if ($scope.subcats[i].id === $scope.subcategory_id)
                {
                    console.log($scope.subcats[i].name);
                    $scope.subcat_selected_name = $scope.subcats[i].name;
                    alert($scope.subcat_selected_name);
                }
            }
```

where as `$scope.subcategory_id` has value `1` but it does not work. But if I write something like this `if ($scope.subcats[i].id ===1)` It does run.

Comment: I solved it with if ($scope.subcats[i].id == $scope.subcategory_id) double equals not triple

Comment: I guess `$scope.subcategory_id` is a *string* and the other is a *number*, so `===` will not work...

Answer (score 0):

Using triple equals is mostly recommended. Along with the values, triple equals also checks the types of the operators. Maybe the types of $scope.subcategory_id and the elements of $scope.subcats array are not the same.

Make their type the same if you can. If you cannot do that and if you don't see any risks about the types, you can continue using double equals.

Comment: $scope.subcategory_id  is an object while $scope.subcats is an array

Comment: I said: "the elements of $scope.subcats array". The type of the $scope.subcategory_id and the elements of the array need to be same in order to use triple equals.